# vim unite-grepで特定のファイル(*.h など)のみ検索する方法について

Tags: vim

最近uniteを入れて、uniteなしのvimには戻れない位に依存しているのですが、
ファイル拡張子を指定したunite-grepの方法がわからず、ファイル指定したい場合のみ

```
:Ag HOGE -G \.h$
```

のようにag.vimを使用しています。
できれば全部uniteのみで完結させたいのですが、どうすれば可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

grep 自体にはファイルパターンを指定するオプションがないので、`unite-grep` は直接はサポートしていないようです。
内部で使っているコマンドに引数を渡すことはできるので、`unite-grep` が ag を使う設定になっているのであれば、

```
:Unite grep::-G\ \\.h$
```

とすることで指定することは可能なようです。